# can we use term suggester while indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Can we use term suggester while indexing? The documentation talks only about searching an index. Our need is to have additional field to store the suggested term and also the actual word.

Comment: so, let's say you have a document with word: apple, and during indexing you want to find a suggestion, e.g. - banana (just naive example) and then index both words?

Comment: yes, if I say aple then while indexing I need aple and apple in different fields

Comment: no, it's not possible to do via suggester, you could use manual synonyms